# Trouble referencing variable in Collections.where method within render function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have run into some trouble with a piece of backbone code. The code below relates to a render function. I can retrieve all the models. My trouble arises when I try to use the "Collections.where" method at line marked number #1. As you can see, I have passed an object literal into the render function but for some reason I am unable to reference it within the customers.where method on line #1. When I give this method a literal number like 45 it works. Is there some way around this so I can pass the variable reference in?

Thanks alot

```
render: function(options) {

    var that = this;
    if (options.id) {

        var customers = new Customers();
        customers.fetch({
            success: function (customers) {
   /* #1 --> */ var musketeers = customers.where({musketeerId: options.id});
                console.log(musketeers.length) //doesn't work as options.id is failing on last line
                var template = _.template($('#customer-list-template').html(), {
                    customers: customers.models
                });
                that.$el.html(template);
                console.log(customers.models);
            }
        });

    } else {
        var template = _.template($('#customer-list-template').html(), {});
        that.$el.html(template);
    }
}
```

Comment: Anybody know how to pass in a dynamic value to an object literal or a way around this? Thanks

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error?

Comment: When I say this  ->> var musketeers = customers.where({musketeerId: 10}); I get the value 100 for musketeer.length. When I use a variable with a value of 10 like options.id = 10 and say var musketeers = customers.where({musketeerId: options.id}); I get 0 for musketeer.length

Comment: Are you certain that `options.id` is `45` rather than `'45'`?

Comment: @muistooshort - Hey you were right. I wasn't even aware that those difference arose in javascript. Thanks v much for the help. I'd like to upvote but I haven't got enough points yet. If you move the answer below I will mark it as the right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it isn't explicitly documented, [`Collection#where`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) uses [strict equality (`===`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) when searching. From the [fine source code](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-101):

```
where: function(attrs, first) {
  if (_.isEmpty(attrs)) return first ? void 0 : [];
  return this[first ? 'find' : 'filter'](function(model) {
    for (var key in attrs) {
      if (attrs[key] !== model.get(key)) return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
},
```

note the `attrs[key] !== model.get(key)` inside the callback function, that won't consider `10` (a probable `id` value) and `'10'` (a probable search value extracted from an `<input>`) to be a match. That means that:

```
customers.where({musketeerId: 10});
```

might find something whereas:

```
customers.where({musketeerId: '10'});
```

won't.

You can get around this sort of thing with [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
// Way off where you extract values from the `<input>`...
options.id = parseInt($input.val(), 10);
```