# Object literals and dynamic variables

Tags: javascript, web-services, backbone.js

Can someone point me in the right direction? How do you pass a reference variable in to an object literal in JavaScript? I am using Backbone.js and specifically I am using the `collections.where` method. So I have something as follows:

```
var temp = customers.where({num: 10});
```

However, what if someone has a variable like var x (that changes) and they want to say something like the following:

```
var temp = customers.where({num: x});
```

JavaScript won't let you do this, I know. But how is it done or how do you get around it?

Comment: Did you try it? This works: `var x = 10; var temp = customers.where({num: x});`.  Maybe be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: JavaScript will let you do that just fine. It is the *property name* (as opposed to the *value*) that isn't an evaluated expression.

Comment: @PaulHoenecke http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710923/trouble-referencing-variable-in-collections-where-method-within-render-function - Please could you take a look at the code on that link. I think it may be a closure issue as pointed out below. I am very new to javascript

Comment: Not looking (I guess it's a good thing I have a different last name) - anyway, have a -1 (which can be reverted). Explain *your problem* with the *full [but minimal] context* and failure indicators or unexpected behavior.

Comment: Sorry there is no closure issue in the code you have provided here.  If `x` is defined and a number there is no problem with this code. Again... revise your question to actually show the problem you are having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a closure over `x` like this:

```
var x = 10;
var filter = function() { return customers.where({num: x}); };

var temp = filter(); // uses x = 10

x = 20;
temp = filter(); // uses x = 20
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will research closures tomorrow more fully