# Strange Backbone findWhere() behavior

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I am building an app with Backbone & RequireJS, and I am incredibly confused by the behavior here of the `Collection.findWhere()` Backbone function.

When the code is this:

```
var myId = 1;
var subList = parentList.findWhere({id: myId});
```

subList shows as `undefined`.

When the code is this:

```
var subList = parentList.findWhere({id: 1});
```

subList contains the correct model.

Does anyone know what could possible cause this?

Comment: Your code should work. There is something else is going on in your code which is now lost in the simplification. Are you absolutely sure when using `{id: myId}` then the `myId` variable hold the correct id? Maybe it is a string not an int... You should try to reproduce your issue in a JSFiddle and post the repro here.

Comment: I can not reproduce the isse either : http://jsfiddle.net/yAg3F/

Comment: Well that's embarassing... nemesv you were correct, id did contain a string instead of an int. Fixed that and everything works fine.

Comment: Same thing as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15710923/479863).

Comment: Same issue here, with Backbone (version 1.0.0), the .findWhere( {id: aid } ) and .get( aid ) did not return same value.  FindWhere were returning an undefined.  I switched to col.get( id ).